# How to remove percent sign from url

Tags: c#, asp.net

By mistake I have made few asp pages having % sign.For example 100%cotton.aspx. Now when i am trying to open it on url.it says: *Bad Request - Invalid URL  HTTP Error 400*. The request URL is invalid. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: rename the pages to be have the correct names.

Comment: agreed with ashutosh raina

Comment: Or you can simply try some url rewriting

Comment: What Url you are trying to open? % is ok in "path" portion of Url, but need to be properly encoded as %25.

Comment: Ashutosh Raina & Alexei Levenkov have given the answer: 1 way it to rename your page to exclude "%", another way is to encode url before page redirect.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what the problem is but properly encoded `%` in the path should not cause problems. % is ok in "path" portion of Url, but need to be properly encoded as %25.

The best way to deal with all encoding is to use `Uri` or `UriBuilder` classes to construct urls:

```
 var url = new Uri("http://foo/bar%test").AbsoluteUri
```

The other option (as suggested by  ashutosh raina) is to simply not use % in file names. Note that it does not mean you should not be constructing urls properly.